# Angularjs bootstrap tabset tab heading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

I am wondering whether it is possible to write html inside an angularjs bootstrap tabset tab heading. I am trying to add a svg inside the title. I have created a quick snippet in plunker to try and demonstrate the issue I am having.

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="<span>hello</span><em>1</em>">One</tab>
  <tab heading="Two">Two</tab>
  <tab heading="Three">Three</tab>
</tabset>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qFsFGDNUIJj9nIF51ApU

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Angular Bootstrap v0.14+

Angular Bootstrap v0.14 [introduced new prefixes](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0140-2015-10-09) for most previously provided controls. The original answer below still applies, but you must use the new tag names `uib-tabset`, `uib-tab`, and `uib-tab-heading`.

```
<uib-tabset>
  <uib-tab>
    <uib-tab-heading>
      <span>hello</span><em>1</em>
    </uib-tab-heading>
    One
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Two">Two</uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Three">Three</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

## Angular Bootstrap < v0.14

You should be using the `tab-heading` element within the `tab` element if you want HTML within the heading (as shown in the example in the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)):

```
<tabset>
  <tab>
    <tab-heading>
      <span>hello</span><em>1</em>
    </tab-heading>
    One
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Two">Two</tab>
  <tab heading="Three">Three</tab>
</tabset>
```

Updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3YeA0Qg0LFJrYzAsIZa?p=preview).

Comment: Bare in mind that if you're trying to get this to work in IE8 then you need to use attributes rather than elements. So: `<div tabset><div tab><div tab-heading><span>hello</span></div></div></div>`

Answer (score 5):

## Since 2016

The accepted answer is ok for the *ui-bootstrap* prior `version 0.14.0`, since version `0.14.0` *(2015.10.09)* tabs use `uib-` prefix.

See [changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0140-2015-10-09)

So you have to replace all tags with `uib-` prefix

```
<uib-tabset>
  <uib-tab>
    <uib-tab-heading>
      <span>hello</span><em>1</em>
    </uib-tab-heading>
    One
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Two">Two</uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Three">Three</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Taylor Buchanan's answer is the correct answer!

Looking at the template used by the tabs directive, the headings content will be escaped: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/192768e109b5c4a50c7dcd320e09d05fedd4298a/template/tabs/tab.html#L2

So it is not possible to use html in your headings.

---

You can create a work-around by re-defining the tab template like so:

```
angular.module("template/tabs/tab.html").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/tabs/tab.html",
    "<li ng-class=\"{active: active, disabled: disabled}\">\n" +
    "  <a ng-click=\"select()\" tab-heading-transclude ng-bind-html=\"heading\"></a>\n" +
    "</li>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

You will also need to nclude angular-sanitize.js to safely bind html contents.

Working Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ep5f1GY12vSixT4xtxFy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I will give this is a shot and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your TAB tag an id and then use jQuery to augment the html.
              ...tab id="myid"....

and then
              jQuery("#myid").html("**New Html**")

Comment: This is not in line with "The Angular Way". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score -1):

```
            <li heading="Status" class="ng-isolate-scope var" ng-model="(var = 'active: active')" >
                <a href="/ibox">Status1</a>
            </li>


            <li heading="Status" class="ng-isolate-scope var" ng-model="var = 'active: active'">
                <a href="/netapp">Status</a>
            </li>


    </tabset>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Additionally, this does not attempt to answer the question.