# Need equivalent syntax using ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-bind

How can replace the `{{eachTab.tabName}}` with `ng-bind` in the following code?

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs" heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}"
         select="createRecsforeachTab(dSet, eachTab)">
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: could you try, <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs"><tab-heading ng-bind-html="eachTab.tabName"></tab-heading></tab>

Comment: Do you mean <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs"><tab-heading ng-bind-html="eachTab.tabName" select="createRecsforeachTab(dSet, eachTab)"></tab-heading></tab> ?

Comment: or <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs" select="createRecsforeachTab(dSet, eachTab)"><tab-heading ng-bind-html="eachTab.tabName" ></tab-heading></tab> ?

Comment: 2nd one, if you are using ng-bind-html don't forget to include ngSanitize.

Comment: This question makes little sense. `ng-bind` is used to bind the text content of an element to interpolated expression. It was never used or meant to be used for an attribute. What is wrong with `heading="{{expr}}"`?

Comment: @NewDev, you might be aware of angularjs initial flickering issue with {{ }} syntax, particularly when the to be loaded Html content is too large. To avoid that few developers are suggesting to use ng-bind instead {{ }} as one of the solutions. I hope it answered your question.

Comment: @mnkb, yes, but that is only applicable for text content, not for attributes. Attributes would not flicker

Comment: Really!!!. But when I use,  <tabset> <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs" heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}" select="createRecsforeachTab(dSet, eachTab)"> </tab> </tabset> , I am getting flickering with tab names appearance, so I am on the way of fixing it using ng-bind. Each of my tab loads 4 to 5 charts (like line charts/bar charts, etc) or some complex tables and  my tab names are getting effected with this flickering problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the ng-repeat into the tabset scope like so:

```
<tabset ng-repeat="eachTab in rowTabs">
    <tab heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}" ng-bind-html="{{eachTab.tabName}}" select="createRecsforeachTab(dSet, eachTab)"> </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered! [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

The following code is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26102981/4749156) by @badsyntax

```
angular.module("template/tabs/tab.html").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/tabs/tab.html",
    "<li ng-class=\"{active: active, disabled: disabled}\">\n" +
    "  <a ng-click=\"select()\" tab-heading-transclude ng-bind-html=\"heading\"></a>\n" +
    "</li>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```